# How to implement Monthly Subscription in inapp purchase in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

Hi i'am Very New to inApp Purchase and i want to implement Monthly subscription in my App.

My Application Recently Rejected  and here is the status :

**We found your app uses auto renewing subscriptions but is not a periodical, business app, or media app. Auto renewing subscriptions are intended for these types of apps only; other uses do not comply with the App Store Review Guidelines.
It would be appropriate to change your In-App Purchase product to a non-renewing subscription.**

So please guide me the best way to implement Monthly subscription in my app in legal way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi i Answered This Question After making a lot of Research and googling around the Web so that other can be get Help From it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/13_ManagingIn-AppPurchases_Robert/ManagingIn-AppPurchases.html

in the Above Link Apple Documented about Non-Renewing iAp

**Non-Renewing Subscription allow the sale of services with a limited duration. Non-Renewing Subscriptions must be used for in-app purchases that offer time-based access to static content and are only available to iOS apps.
If you use non-renewing subscription, your app is responsible for delivering the subscription to all the user's devices.
Because a non-renewing subscription requires a user to renew each time, your app must contain code that recognizes when the subscription is due to expire. It must also prompt the user to purchase a new subscription.**

So i simple Changed my Purchase type to **Non-Renewing Subscription** And i Changed my Code to Alert user that recognizes when the subscription is due to expire and It must also prompt the user to purchase a new subscription.

Comment: But Evernote does that and their app is not got rejected.Seems strange!!